# Checking the lowest id value of a set of elements

Tags: jquery

Say if I had this:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="9"></div>
<div id="10"></div>
```

And I wanted to get the lowest value of all of these divs. Obviously, the lowest value is 1 right there, but say if I deleted the divs, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10 not in any order, how would I get the lowest value if it is constantly changing.

Sorry for the poorly explained question, I am not very good at wording things.

Comment: ID's can't start with a number

Comment: @myfunkyside: They can in HTML5 and browser supported it before it was formalized.

Comment: Get all divs, sort by id value and get the first element from the list.

Comment: answer: give them all the same class **>** iterate over them, storing all their ID's in an array **>** sort the array **>** it's THE FIRST ELEMENT in the array`

Comment: @FelixKling - Huh, did not know that. Thanks. I'll stay on the safe side though and start my ID's with an alphabetical character

Answer (score 1):

```
    function get_lowest(){

         var array = [];

          $('div').each(function() {

               var id = $(this).attr('id');

                array.push(id);
            });

           console.log(array);

           var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array);

           console.log(min);

           return min;
  }

 var lowest_val = get_lowest();

 console.log(lowest_val );
```

I put it inside a function so it's reusable, but you could easily associate with an object or pass in an array into the function do it that way.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwv3feq9/

Comment: you can just use `array.sort();`, it's a lot lighter than using `Math`

Comment: Sorting is O(n*log(n)). Finding the minimum is O(n). There's no need to sort the whole thing when you're just going to throw away most of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
for(var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div'),min=divs[0].id,i=0,l=divs.length-1;i<l;(divs[++i].id<min)&&(min=divs[i].id));
```

This is an highly optimized code, and works! Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/sdbvok7g/

Lets make it verbose:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); //no jQuery!

var min = divs[0].id; //assign the 1st id, we can skip 1 iteration

for (var i = 1; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    if (divs[i].id < min) //if the id is lower than the min
    {
        min = divs[i].id; //assign the new id
    }
}
```

This one also works too, a bit slower.

You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/qksgLd0a/2/

**Notice**: On both fiddles, I put the highest id first. The order can be random!

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated. Following suggestion by Felix Kling

Given removal of random items `[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10]` from within the set `[1-10]` ; remaining elements being randomly ordered within the document , find the element whose `id` is "lowest" (numerically) within the set

html

```
<div id="7">7</div>
<div id="9">9</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

js

```
var el = $("#" + $("div").map(function() {return Number(this.id)}).sort()[0]);
```

```js
var el = $("#" + $("div").map(function() {return Number(this.id)}).sort()[0]);
el.css("color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="7">7</div>
<div id="9">9</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted here seem quite complex so I thought I'd throw a simpler solution in the mix:

```
var lowest_val = Math.min.apply(null, $('div').map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
}).get());

console.log(lowest_val);
```